# How to concatenate a Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

My questions refers to a "concatenation" of a Python dictionary. For example: I have a dictionary `di = {1:'AB', 2:'BC',3:'CD'}`, and I want with one command `print(____)` to get the output `'ABCD'`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you explain what algorithm produces "ABCD"? Does it relate to the keys being numeric and in order? Or does it perhaps relate to "AB" ending in "B" and "BC" starting with "B", etc.? Maybe giving another example or two would help. (Why isn't the output "ABC" or "ABBCCD"?)

Comment: it is related to AB" ending in "B" and "BC" starting with "B", etc. Its like i want to concatenate the str values to one removing the duplicates.

Comment: If the input dictionary were `{3:"BC", 2:"CD", 1:"CE"}`, what output would you expect? (`"BCD"`? `"BCE"`? Something else?)

Comment: One possibility is using set() on all the values to get only the unique letters, then joining them together.

Comment: Not exactly i would like to concatenate the str values and remove the duplicates in the "connection points"

Comment: @StavrosCheristanidis So... what's the expected output for the input I proposed? What you said doesn't really explain it to me. Maybe `"CECDBC"`? (Perhaps the numeric order of the keys matters?)

Comment: Another question to help this along... how do you decide what the first character of the output is?

Comment: @smarx, firstly sorry for being missunderstood. i dont want 'CECDBC', yes the numeric order matters,  i want in one print(___) to get the values in 
 numeric order in one single str without the duplicates

Comment: If not `"CECDBC"`, what *do* you want?

Comment: (I would think that "the values in numeric order in one single str without the duplicates" would be `"CECDBC"` or maybe `"CEDB"` depending on how you define duplicates.)

Comment: in my example if i ask for print(di[1]+di[2]+di[3]) i get ABBCCD but i want ABCD, any suggestion on how can i do that?

Comment: I thank you all for your help!!! i find it! you 're wonderful!

Comment: @StavrosCheristanidis Please add your solution as an answer, then, and accept it. (I'm quite curious as to what you were actually trying to do, so I'd love to see the solution.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Hope  that this is what you wanted
di = {1:'AB', 2:'BC',3:'CD'}

print((di[1]+di[2]+di[3]).replace((di[2]),''))
```

Comment: thanx but i want the command in one print. print(_____)

Comment: Please try to elaborate for Me what you mean wanting the command in one print.

Comment: I have the dictionary di = {1:'AB', 2:'BC',3:'CD'}, and I want with one print(what should i write between the braggets) to get the output 'ABCD'

Comment: Will that do it for you?

Comment: no because it doesn't remove the duplicates. It gets ABBCCD. I would like ABCD

Comment: How about that?

Comment: yeap it works, thanks

Comment: You can simplify the answer here to `print(di[1]+di[3])`. That can't possibly be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try This One.

```
print(''.join(str(e) for e in list(sorted(set(di[1]+di[2]+di[3]))))
```

Comment: So the numerical order *doesn't* matter after all?

Comment: `print(''.join(sorted(set(''.join(di.values())))))` is a more general version of this. (This way you don't need to know in advance how many items are in the dictionary and what their keys are.)

Comment: @smarx, thanx for your idea, it also works!

Comment: @stavcher To clarify, what this answer does is take all the letters that appear in the values in the dictionary and puts them in alphabetical order. I don't see how you can like this solution as well as the other solution and also claim that the numerical order of the keys in the dictionary matters.